# CSV reader fails to return Strings

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have a CSV file  that has following form.

I read the CSV using CSV reader. It outputs the objects in following form instead of the string.

### Output

[Ljava.lang.String;@138617da

**

This is my code. What is wrong with code?

```
   public  void readFeatures () throws IOException{
            File(classLoader.getResource(filename).getFile());

    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file));
    List myEntries = reader.readAll();

    for( int i = 0; i< myEntries.size(); i ++){
        System.out.println(myEntries.get(i).toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Beyond that : read about raw types and stop using them.

Answer (score 1):

remember that you are reading an array or arrays of Strings.

The output is showing that you are trying to print an Array `[L` of Strings

Either create an inner loop, or try using `Arrays.toString (myEntries.get(i))`